# Algorithm for generating smooth curves from incoming data points

Tags: python, gaussian, smoothing

I'm looking for an algorithm that smoothly interpolates points as they come in *live*.

For example, say I start with an array of 10 (x,y) pairs. I'm currently using scipy and a gaussian window to generate a smooth curve. However, what I can't figure out is how to update the smoothed curve in response to an 11th point generated at some future point (without completely redoing the smoothing for all 11 points).

What I'm looking for is an algorithm that **follows the previous smooth curve up to the 10th (x,y) pair** and **also** smoothly interpolates between the 10th and 11th pair (in a way that's similar to redoing the entire algorithm - so no sharp edges). Is there something out there that does what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could make use of a [Cubic Spline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html). Given a list of `n` points `(x_1, y_1)..(x_n, y_n)`, the algorithm finds a cubic polynomial `p_k` between `(x_k, y_k)` and `(x_{k+1}, y_{k+1})` with the following constraints:

- polynomials `p_k` and `p_{k+1}` passes through the point `(x_{k+1}, y_{k+1})`;
- polynomials `p_k` and `p_{k+1}` have the same first derivative at `(x_{k+1}, y_{k+1})`;
- polynomials `p_k` and `p_{k+1}` have the same second derivative at `(x_{k+1}, y_{k+1})`.

Also, there are some boundary conditions, defined for the first and the last polynomial. I have used `natural`, which forces the second derivative to zero at the end of the curves.

The steps that you could apply are:

1. Interpolate the first 10 points using the Cubic Spline.
2. Assign the first derivative value at `p_10` to a variable `d`.
3. Run the Cubic Spline for `p_10` and `p_11`, enforcing that the first derivative at `p_10` is `d` and the second derivative at `p_11` is zero.

From there, you can repeat the same steps for the remaining points.

This code will generate a interpolation for all points:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

height=4
n = 20
x = np.arange(n)
xs = np.arange(-0.1,n+0.1,0.1)
y = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=height, size=n)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='data')
cs = CubicSpline(x, y)
plt.plot(xs, cs(xs), color='orange')
plt.ylim([0, height+1])
```

[image: Interpolation for 20 points]

Now, this code will interpolate the first 10 points, followed by another interpolation between points 10 and 11:

```py
k = 10
delta = 0.001

plt.plot(x, y, 'o', label='data')
xs = np.arange(x[0], x[k-1]+delta, delta)
cs = CubicSpline(x[0:k], y[0:k])
plt.plot(xs, cs(xs), color='red')

d = cs(x[k-1], 1)

xs2 = np.arange(x[k-1], x[k]+delta, delta)
cs2 = CubicSpline(x[k-1:k+1], y[k-1:k+1], bc_type=((1, d), 'natural'))
plt.plot(xs2, cs2(xs2), color='blue')

plt.ylim([0, height+1])
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is **exactly** what I was looking for. Thank you so much!